# Replicate a row n times with different index in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a timeseries dataset 1 with a step of 1 hour :

[image]

And I have another timeseries dataset 2 with a step of 15 minutes:

[image]

I want the first dataset to have the same time step (of 15 minutes) than the second one, by replicating each row 4 times and changing the time indexes to be the same as the second dataset.

Is there an easy way to do that without any errors ?

Comment: Yes, use np.repeat(4) and use timedelta() to add the time. If you want help, you need to share data as clear text. No one can recreate the problem if you share images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Option 1: Using [pd.Index.repeat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) and [pd.Timedelta()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 200)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'timestamp':['2019-11-25T00:00:00','2019-11-25T01:00:00','2019-11-25T02:00:00','2019-11-25T03:00:00','2019-11-25T04:00:00'],
    'temperature':[8.7,8.8,8.9,8.8,8.8],
    'wind_speed':[11.0,9.0,8.0,7.0,10.0],
    'wind_gust_speed':[24.0,20.0,18.0,18.0,23.0],
    'rain_level':[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],
    'traffic_state':['Fluid']*5,
    'average_flow':[218.1,144.3,110.0,143.8,315.1]
    })

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])


df4 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(4)].reset_index(drop=True)
df4['timestamp'] = df4.apply(lambda x: x.timestamp + pd.Timedelta(minutes=(x.name%4)*15), axis=1)
print (df4)
```

The output of this will be:

```
             timestamp  temperature  wind_speed  wind_gust_speed  rain_level  \
0  2019-11-25 00:00:00          8.7        11.0             24.0         0.0   
1  2019-11-25 00:15:00          8.7        11.0             24.0         0.0   
2  2019-11-25 00:30:00          8.7        11.0             24.0         0.0   
3  2019-11-25 00:45:00          8.7        11.0             24.0         0.0   
4  2019-11-25 01:00:00          8.8         9.0             20.0         0.0   
5  2019-11-25 01:15:00          8.8         9.0             20.0         0.0   
6  2019-11-25 01:30:00          8.8         9.0             20.0         0.0   
7  2019-11-25 01:45:00          8.8         9.0             20.0         0.0   
8  2019-11-25 02:00:00          8.9         8.0             18.0         0.0   
9  2019-11-25 02:15:00          8.9         8.0             18.0         0.0   
10 2019-11-25 02:30:00          8.9         8.0             18.0         0.0   
11 2019-11-25 02:45:00          8.9         8.0             18.0         0.0   
12 2019-11-25 03:00:00          8.8         7.0             18.0         0.0   
13 2019-11-25 03:15:00          8.8         7.0             18.0         0.0   
14 2019-11-25 03:30:00          8.8         7.0             18.0         0.0   
15 2019-11-25 03:45:00          8.8         7.0             18.0         0.0   
16 2019-11-25 04:00:00          8.8        10.0             23.0         0.0   
17 2019-11-25 04:15:00          8.8        10.0             23.0         0.0   
18 2019-11-25 04:30:00          8.8        10.0             23.0         0.0   
19 2019-11-25 04:45:00          8.8        10.0             23.0         0.0   

   traffic_state  average_flow  
0          Fluid         218.1  
1          Fluid         218.1  
2          Fluid         218.1  
3          Fluid         218.1  
4          Fluid         144.3  
5          Fluid         144.3  
6          Fluid         144.3  
7          Fluid         144.3  
8          Fluid         110.0  
9          Fluid         110.0  
10         Fluid         110.0  
11         Fluid         110.0  
12         Fluid         143.8  
13         Fluid         143.8  
14         Fluid         143.8  
15         Fluid         143.8  
16         Fluid         315.1  
17         Fluid         315.1  
18         Fluid         315.1  
19         Fluid         315.1
```

Below are other options I tried to solve before I did the np.repeat. These address the problem but have limitations. I have explained them for you.

## Option 2: Using [df.asfreq('15min')](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html)

I don't know if you were able to quickly get through this. You can also use `df.asfreq('15min')` to create the 15 minute interval. First you need to set_index on  `timestamp` as df.asfreq() works on series.

Here's how to do it:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 200)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'timestamp':['2019-11-25T00:00:00','2019-11-25T01:00:00','2019-11-25T02:00:00','2019-11-25T03:00:00','2019-11-25T04:00:00'],
    'temperature':[8.7,8.8,8.9,8.8,8.8],
    'wind_speed':[11.0,9.0,8.0,7.0,10.0],
    'wind_gust_speed':[24.0,20.0,18.0,18.0,23.0],
    'rain_level':[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],
    'traffic_state':['Fluid']*5,
    'average_flow':[218.1,144.3,110.0,143.8,315.1]
    })

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df = df.set_index('timestamp')
df1 = df.asfreq('15min').reset_index().ffill()

print (df1)


             timestamp  temperature  wind_speed  wind_gust_speed  rain_level  \
0  2019-11-25 00:00:00          8.7        11.0             24.0         0.0   
1  2019-11-25 00:15:00          8.7        11.0             24.0         0.0   
2  2019-11-25 00:30:00          8.7        11.0             24.0         0.0   
3  2019-11-25 00:45:00          8.7        11.0             24.0         0.0   
4  2019-11-25 01:00:00          8.8         9.0             20.0         0.0   
5  2019-11-25 01:15:00          8.8         9.0             20.0         0.0   
6  2019-11-25 01:30:00          8.8         9.0             20.0         0.0   
7  2019-11-25 01:45:00          8.8         9.0             20.0         0.0   
8  2019-11-25 02:00:00          8.9         8.0             18.0         0.0   
9  2019-11-25 02:15:00          8.9         8.0             18.0         0.0   
10 2019-11-25 02:30:00          8.9         8.0             18.0         0.0   
11 2019-11-25 02:45:00          8.9         8.0             18.0         0.0   
12 2019-11-25 03:00:00          8.8         7.0             18.0         0.0   
13 2019-11-25 03:15:00          8.8         7.0             18.0         0.0   
14 2019-11-25 03:30:00          8.8         7.0             18.0         0.0   
15 2019-11-25 03:45:00          8.8         7.0             18.0         0.0   
16 2019-11-25 04:00:00          8.8        10.0             23.0         0.0   

   traffic_state  average_flow  
0          Fluid         218.1  
1          Fluid         218.1  
2          Fluid         218.1  
3          Fluid         218.1  
4          Fluid         144.3  
5          Fluid         144.3  
6          Fluid         144.3  
7          Fluid         144.3  
8          Fluid         110.0  
9          Fluid         110.0  
10         Fluid         110.0  
11         Fluid         110.0  
12         Fluid         143.8  
13         Fluid         143.8  
14         Fluid         143.8  
15         Fluid         143.8  
16         Fluid         315.1
```

Note here that the last row did not increment by 15 mins. If you want to do that, you need to use repeat.

## Option 3: Using [df.resample('15min')](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) excluding columns with strings

We can also try and do 'resample `but it will not retain the string datatypes (`traffic_state` does not get copied over).

If you want to use `df.resample`, you can give:

```
df2 = df.resample('15min',on='timestamp').mean().reset_index().ffill()
print (df2)
```

This will result in:

```
             timestamp  temperature  wind_speed  wind_gust_speed  rain_level  \
0  2019-11-25 00:00:00          8.7        11.0             24.0         0.0   
1  2019-11-25 00:15:00          8.7        11.0             24.0         0.0   
2  2019-11-25 00:30:00          8.7        11.0             24.0         0.0   
3  2019-11-25 00:45:00          8.7        11.0             24.0         0.0   
4  2019-11-25 01:00:00          8.8         9.0             20.0         0.0   
5  2019-11-25 01:15:00          8.8         9.0             20.0         0.0   
6  2019-11-25 01:30:00          8.8         9.0             20.0         0.0   
7  2019-11-25 01:45:00          8.8         9.0             20.0         0.0   
8  2019-11-25 02:00:00          8.9         8.0             18.0         0.0   
9  2019-11-25 02:15:00          8.9         8.0             18.0         0.0   
10 2019-11-25 02:30:00          8.9         8.0             18.0         0.0   
11 2019-11-25 02:45:00          8.9         8.0             18.0         0.0   
12 2019-11-25 03:00:00          8.8         7.0             18.0         0.0   
13 2019-11-25 03:15:00          8.8         7.0             18.0         0.0   
14 2019-11-25 03:30:00          8.8         7.0             18.0         0.0   
15 2019-11-25 03:45:00          8.8         7.0             18.0         0.0   
16 2019-11-25 04:00:00          8.8        10.0             23.0         0.0   

    average_flow  
0          218.1  
1          218.1  
2          218.1  
3          218.1  
4          144.3  
5          144.3  
6          144.3  
7          144.3  
8          110.0  
9          110.0  
10         110.0  
11         110.0  
12         143.8  
13         143.8  
14         143.8  
15         143.8  
16         315.1
```

Again this also does not increment the last row by 15 minutes.

## Option 4: Using df.resample('15min') including columns with strings (use lambda)

```
df3 = df.resample('15min',on='timestamp').agg({'temperature':'mean','wind_speed':'mean',
                                               'wind_gust_speed':'mean','rain_level':'mean',
                                               'traffic_state':lambda x: x if len(x)>0 else np.nan,
                                               'average_flow':'mean'}).reset_index().ffill()
print (df3)
```

Output will be:

```
             timestamp  temperature  wind_speed  wind_gust_speed  rain_level  \
0  2019-11-25 00:00:00          8.7        11.0             24.0         0.0   
1  2019-11-25 00:15:00          8.7        11.0             24.0         0.0   
2  2019-11-25 00:30:00          8.7        11.0             24.0         0.0   
3  2019-11-25 00:45:00          8.7        11.0             24.0         0.0   
4  2019-11-25 01:00:00          8.8         9.0             20.0         0.0   
5  2019-11-25 01:15:00          8.8         9.0             20.0         0.0   
6  2019-11-25 01:30:00          8.8         9.0             20.0         0.0   
7  2019-11-25 01:45:00          8.8         9.0             20.0         0.0   
8  2019-11-25 02:00:00          8.9         8.0             18.0         0.0   
9  2019-11-25 02:15:00          8.9         8.0             18.0         0.0   
10 2019-11-25 02:30:00          8.9         8.0             18.0         0.0   
11 2019-11-25 02:45:00          8.9         8.0             18.0         0.0   
12 2019-11-25 03:00:00          8.8         7.0             18.0         0.0   
13 2019-11-25 03:15:00          8.8         7.0             18.0         0.0   
14 2019-11-25 03:30:00          8.8         7.0             18.0         0.0   
15 2019-11-25 03:45:00          8.8         7.0             18.0         0.0   
16 2019-11-25 04:00:00          8.8        10.0             23.0         0.0   

   traffic_state  average_flow  
0          Fluid         218.1  
1          Fluid         218.1  
2          Fluid         218.1  
3          Fluid         218.1  
4          Fluid         144.3  
5          Fluid         144.3  
6          Fluid         144.3  
7          Fluid         144.3  
8          Fluid         110.0  
9          Fluid         110.0  
10         Fluid         110.0  
11         Fluid         110.0  
12         Fluid         143.8  
13         Fluid         143.8  
14         Fluid         143.8  
15         Fluid         143.8  
16         Fluid         315.1
```

Again, same problem. We are not addressing the last row with 15 min increments.